# unable to add element to the list

Tags: javascript

I need a little help in javascript.

Actually, I want to add the ***list item*** to in the **ul tag** given in the **HTML**, with the help of **javascript**.
When I click on the **button** it should **add** the element in the **ul tag**.

```
Here is the code for HTML-


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<title>Document</title>

</head>
<body>
<input type="text" id="insertTheElement" placeholder="Enter Text Here..."> 
<br><br><br>
<button id="upperMostButton" onclick="listItem()">Add The Content</button>
<ul id="onlyThisOne">
</ul>
<script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here Goes the code for JavaScript-

```
var contentOfList=document.getElementById('insertTheElement').value;
function listItem(contentOfList){
var AddingListItem=document.createElement('li');
AddingListItem.innerText=contentOfList;
document.body.ul.appendChild(AddingListItem);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`document.body.ul` makes no sense. If you need to find direct children of an `HTML Element` you should use `.children`.

Also, you need to get the value of the input element inside the function as this is a one-time copy of value, not a bound variable.

See the snippet below

```js
function listItem(contentOfList) {
  var contentOfList = document.getElementById('insertTheElement').value;
  var AddingListItem = document.createElement('li');
  AddingListItem.innerText = contentOfList;
  document.getElementById('onlyThisOne').appendChild(AddingListItem);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="insertTheElement" placeholder="Enter Text Here..." />
<button id="upperMostButton" onclick="listItem()">Add The Content</button>
<ul id="onlyThisOne">
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code has some issues, you have written the function with input argument, that was not passed, which might have caused undefined items to be appended to your ul element. Moreover you can refer your ul interms of its id inorder to avoid confusion in future when there may be more than one ul element in your page, you can try the following code to achieve your requirement.

```js
function listItem(){
var contentOfList=document.getElementById('insertTheElement').value;
var AddingListItem=document.createElement('li');
AddingListItem.innerText=contentOfList;
document.getElementById('onlyThisOne').appendChild(AddingListItem);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="insertTheElement" placeholder="Enter Text Here..."> 
<br><br><br>
<button id="upperMostButton" onclick="listItem()">Add The Content</button>
<ul id="onlyThisOne">
</ul>
```

Comment: It would be nice if you explain what and why you change. Just giving code is not SO's objective.